# How to append values to DOM from dropdown generated by angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The scenario is:

> 1.Load content from controller into `<select>`.
>   2.Append every selected item in the dropdown, to a `<p>` tag, such that it looks like a **list**

.

First part is done right. Now I'm not getting how to 'append' the selected item. Until now what I could do is, display the selected item in a

tag. But new item replaces the old, where I want it to be added next to the previous.

**Markup**

```
<div id='content' ng-app='MyTutorialApp' ng-controller='MainController'>
        <h1>My Shopping List</h1>
        <select ng-model='selectedItem' ng-options='obj.name for obj in Items'></select>
        <select ng-model='selectedQty'>
                <option ng-repeat="label in Items[selectedItem.id].attr">{{label}}</option>
        </select>
        <p>{{selectedItem.name}}-{{selectedQty}}</p>

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("MainController",function($scope){
            $scope.inputValue="";
            $scope.selectedItem=0;
            $scope.selectedQty=null;
            $scope.Items=[
                    {
                        id:0,
                        name:'Sugar',
                        attr:['0.5 Kg','1 Kg', '2 Kg', '5 Kg']
                    },
                    {
                        id:1,
                        name:'Salt',
                        attr:['0.5 Kg','1 Kg', '2 Kg', '5 Kg']
                    },
                    {
                        id:2,
                        name:'Oil',
                        attr:['500 ml','1 Ltr', '5 Ltr']
                    },
                    {
                        id:3,
                        name:'T-Shirts',
                        attr:['S', 'M', 'L','XL', 'XXL']
                    },
            ]
    });
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `{{selectedItem.name}}-{{selectedQty}}` you **bind** the data from the current scope to this location in your HTML file.
This is not what you want to do (right?), because you want to append all selected values when they are selected.

Try adding something like `ng-change="update()"` to your `<select>` element, and in the controller have a function that appends selected items, **on the scope**:

```
$scope.selectedList = new Array();
$scope.update = function() {
   $scope.selectedList.push($scope.selectedItem.name)
}
```

Not sure it's the exact syntax but hopefully you get the idea.